# Powershell - Replace XML content with an environment variable

Tags: xml, variables, powershell, environment

First, excuse my poor english :)

I've a little headache with the syntax of `Get-Content -Replace`

My code is :

```
(Get-Content $env:HIS_XMLPATH) -replace '<Password>(.*?)</Password>', '<Password>$env:HIS_PWD</Password>' | Set-Content C:\test.xml
```

And the result in the xml file is :

```
<Password>$env:HIS_PWD</Password>
```

I just want the value of my environment variable, what the syntax to include it ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the environment variable inside double quotes so it can be expanded. Single quoted strings are not expandable:

```
... -replace '<Password>(.*?)</Password>', "<Password>$env:HIS_PWD</Password>"
```